# Converting NSString to NSDate returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert the `NSString` to `NSDate` Object in iOS but I am not getting the NSDate object. I am getting nil as date when I passed the string

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM,yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *dateString  = @"2013-10-23 04:04:05";

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: dateString];
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your format doesn't match the input string, so it will fail and return nil.

Comment: That date format looks nothing like the date string. How did you expect it to work?

Answer (score 7):

Well the dateFormat you use is not the one I see in your string.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *dateString = @"2013-10-23 04:04:05";

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: dateString];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do two thing :-

1) change your date format as elio.d has mentioned in the code

2) Your date string should be below format which you had mentioned on your code see below which is specific to your dateformatter and then if you check then you will not get nil

```
   NSString *dateString  = @"23 OCT, 2013    
   04:04:05";
```

Comment: change the format to an unwanted one makes no sense. and if you want to support elio.d, you should add a comment to his answer. in total: useless answer.

Comment: Please read the ans before giving comment as clearly mention in the ans

Comment: I don't see a point why to go in another direction instead of fixing the format. please delete this answer.

Comment: It is not going in another direction it is just explaining why op date is getting nil.